# Implemnt Gyrosensor in ROS

Tags: ros, gyro, robotino, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I would like to use the gyro sensor MPU 6000, which is used on the robotino. It is possible to integrate this gyro sensor in ROS?
If so, is there a manual?

Regards,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355394/implemnt-gyrosensor-in-ros/) by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the following api from the robotino: [here](https://doc.openrobotino.org/download/RobotinoAPI2/rec_robotino_api2/classrec_1_1robotino_1_1api2_1_1_gyroscope.html)

Also i write my own header and my own cpp-File and include it on the robotino_node

```
#include "GyroROS.h"

GyroROS::GyroROS()
{
   gyroscope_pub_ = nh_.advertise<sensor_msgs::Imu>("gyroscope",1, true);
}

GyroROS::~GyroROS()
{
    gyroscope_pub_.shutdown();
}

void GyroROS::setTimeStamp(ros::Time stamp)
{
    stamp_ = stamp;
}

void GyroROS::gyroscopeEvent(float angle, float anglevel)
{

    XAngle = 0.0;
    YAngle = 0.0;
    ZAngle = angle;

    quat = Eigen::AngleAxisf(XAngle, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitX())
           * Eigen::AngleAxisf(YAngle, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitY())
           * Eigen::AngleAxisf(ZAngle, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ());

   gyro_msg_.orientation.x = quat.x();
   gyro_msg_.orientation.y = quat.y();
   gyro_msg_.orientation.z = quat.z();
   gyro_msg_.orientation.w = quat.w();

   gyro_msg_.angular_velocity.z = -anglevel;
   gyro_msg_.header.stamp = stamp_;
   gyro_msg_.header.frame_id = "base_link";

   // Covariance Matrix in Orientation
   gyro_msg_.orientation_covariance[0] = 0.0;
   gyro_msg_.orientation_covariance[4] = 0.0;
   gyro_msg_.orientation_covariance[8] = 0.0;

   // Covariance Matrix in Angule Velocity
   gyro_msg_.angular_velocity_covariance[0] = 0.0;
   gyro_msg_.angular_velocity_covariance[4] = 0.0;
   gyro_msg_.angular_velocity_covariance[8] = 0.0;

   gyroscope_pub_.publish(gyro_msg_);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [MarkusHHN](https://answers.ros.org/users/34687/markushhn/) with karma: 54 on 2020-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1